# Losing encoding when converting from char to string

Tags: c++, string, time, encoding, char

I'm using Codeblocks for a c++ project in Ubuntu. I have the following function for creating a timestamp:

```
char *myclass::getCurrentTime() {

  time_t rawtime;
  struct tm * timeinfo;
  char buffer[30];

  time(&rawtime);
  timeinfo = localtime(&rawtime);

  strftime(buffer, 30, "%d-%m-%YT%H:%M:%S.000+02:00", timeinfo);
  return buffer;
}
```

When I convert the returned char to a string through:

```
char *curr_time = getCurrentTime();
string time_str = string(curr_time);
```

It loses the encoding and if I try to write the string in a file or print it I get undefined characters. If I use the char there are no problems with encoding. Everything was working fine when I was on Visual Studio in Win7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a local variable from the function. You think you are returning an array but what your code is doing is returning a pointer. Arrays can be cast to pointers and this is what happens here. While it is not illegal, it results in undefined behaviour as the array is destroyed when the function returns and you get the garbage you are seeing.

If you want your buffer to be properly allocated, you can declare it that way instead:

```
char* buffer=new char[30];
```

Answer (score 2):

You're returning a *dangling pointer*. After `get CurrentTime` returns the array `buffer` is destroyed, but you still use a pointer to it. This is undefined behaviour - it may sometimes seem to work, but nothing is guaranteed.

If you do the conversion to `string` inside `getCurrentTime` and return that then everything will be fine - part of the point of `string` is to handle this sort of problem for you.